# ASCellNode setting height

Tags: ios, swift, textures

I want my cell's height to fit completely with the height from my ASTableNode, Follow what I found that I need to implement this one

```
override func layoutSpecThatFits(_: ASSizeRange) -> ASLayoutSpec {
}
```

I tried many ways but don't know how to do it properly

Maybe a dumb question but really need some helps

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this in didLoad() method.

node.style.preferredSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `ASTableDelegate`. Set the `delegate` of your `ASTableNode` and then:

```
extension ViewController: ASTableDelegate {
    func tableNode(_: ASTableNode, constrainedSizeForRowAt _: IndexPath) -> ASSizeRange {
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        let heigth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
        let size = CGSize(width: width, height: heigth)
        return ASSizeRangeMake(size, size)
    }
}
```